# What mode to use to decrypt RSA message from iPhone in Java?

Tags: java, iphone, encryption, rsa

My friend has encrypted data with PKCS1 padding on an iPhone.

How can I decrypt that data in Java?

Java requires me to specify "algorithm/ciphermode/padding". The padding and the algorithm are known, but neither of us knows the cipher mode; it is not specified when encrypting on the iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

using [bouncy castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) and [this code](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/RSAexamplewithPKCS1Padding.htm) should be simple

Comment: One more issue here my friend is using iphone there is no bouncy castle in iphone .
So I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

RSA doesn't really use a "mode"; modes are for block ciphers.

The built-in Sun provider will accept "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding" as a `Cipher` name. ECB is "Electronic Code Book", which doesn't mix any information from "block" to block; it is sort of "no cipher mode."

Other providers accept "None" as a cipher mode with RSA.

BouncyCastle is a good provider. I'm not sure why you would need to take the trouble to install it in this case, however. The SunJCE provider will work fine.